# Energy Decay of the functional $\int_{B_1} |Du|^2 +Au^2$

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Suppose $u \in C^1(B_1)$ with $B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\Delta u =0$ weakly. We would have the energy decay estimate
$$\int_{B_r} |Du|^2 \leq r^n \int_{B_1} |Du|^2.$$
Now suppose  $u \in C^1(B_1)$ such that $\Delta u =Au$ weakly and
$$\int_{B_1} |Du|^2+Au^2 \leq 1.$$ Would we have some similar energy decay estimate like 
$$\int_{B_r} |Du|^2 +Au^2 \leq C r^n \int_{B_1} |Du|^2+Au^2$$
with $C$ independent of $A$? Would I also request some reference about the energy minimizer of this type of functional or type of equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one can think of the following counter example on $[-1,1]$:
$$ A(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ for }x\in [-1/2,1/2]\\-1 & \text{if }|x|>1/2
\end{cases}$$
and 
$$ u(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}x^2 & \text{ for }x\in [-1/2,1/2]\\ \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}(1-x)^2 & \text{if } x>1/2 \\ \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}(-1-x)^2 & \text{if } x<-1/2
\end{cases}$$
We have $$\int_{-1}^1 (Du)^2+Au^2 dx = [uDu]_{-1}^1 + \int_{-1}^1 -u \Delta u+Au^2 dx = 0$$
but on the other hand
$$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} (Du)^2+Au^2 dx >0 $$